# MacOS Sierra processes keyboard shortcuts executed with AppleScript differently than prior MacOS versions

Tags: applescript, macos-sierra

On MacOS El Capitan (10.11) and prior it was possible to move between spaces using the following AppleScripts:

```
-- Move Left a Space
tell application "System Events" 
    key code 123 using control down
end tell

-- Move Right a Space
tell application "System Events" 
    key code 124 using control down
end tell
```

On MacOS Sierra (10.12) these scripts will no longer move between spaces. However, when pressing the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Left or Ctrl+Right on the keyboard, MacOS Sierra still moves between spaces.

Strangely enough, when these scripts are run while Xcode is activate, Xcode's text editor cursor will move one word left or right. If these shortcuts (Ctrl+Left, Ctrl+Right) are however pressed on the keyboard, Xcode will not jump between words, but MacOS Sierra will still move between spaces.

It looks like MacOS Sierra has changed the way how keyboard shortcuts are handled by the OS when executed through an AppleScript. They don't execute the same function any longer as when pressed manually on the keyboard.

Now on MacOS Sierra keyboard shortcuts executed with AppleScript will perform the specific action in the active app that's assigned to the keyboard shortcut. MacOS Sierra seems to ignore global shortcuts such as moving between spaces in these cases. Whenever pressed manually, keyboard shortcuts will execute system wide actions and ignore app specific actions, e.g. Xcode will not move between words when Ctrl+Left is pressed manually.

How did this behavior change from El Capitan to Sierra exactly and how can AppleScript again execute global system keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: I have observed many issues with keyboard shortcuts on macOS 10.12 Sierra after upgrading from 10.11. Have you tried the same script with a new user account?

Comment: I haven't yet tried with a new user account. Even if it worked, the shouldn't be the solution.